# Place on earth with the highest minimum temperature?

Tags: where-on-earth, weather-and-climate, factoids

It is easy to find  the place on earth with the lowest minimum or highest maximum temperature ever recorded, but I am wondering where is the place with the highest minimum temperature ever recorded ?

I imagine it would be somewhere on the equator, where the temperatures would not drop below 21C, but I cannot find that information anywhere.

Comment: Or perhaps the Sahara...

Comment: That is the thing - I understand the temperatures in the Sahara can drop significantly at night time

Comment: The Sahara can reach sub-zero temperatures at night. I doubt it would qualify.

Comment: The lowest temperature ever recorded in Singapore is 19.4 degrees, according to Wikipedia. Enjoy your holiday!

Comment: @InsanityRules While I know desert temperatures can drop significantly at night I thought Sahara was a hotter one :-( But yes Singapore or Brazil would probably count.

Comment: Do you mean minimum over a day? or what length of time?

Answer (score 3):

General consensus appears to be Death Valley in the summers, when the minimum temperature of summer nights often remain above 100°F.

World record for hottest overnight low temperature: a minimum temperature of 111.6°F (44.2°C) recorded on the morning of June 17, 2017 at Khasab, Oman.

Dallol, Ethiopia holds the "official" record for [highest average temperature for an inhabited location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dallol,_Ethiopia) on Earth, where an average annual temperature of 35°C (95°F) was recorded between the years 1960 and 1966.

Both authors and commenters note considerable holes in data, such as from the Danakil or Lac Assal depressions in Africa or Dasht-e-Lut in Iran, due to outside difficulties in placing equipment.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_weather_records#Other_high-temperature_records

> - Most consecutive days above 37.8 °C (100 °F): 160 days; Marble Bar, Western Australia from 31 October 1923 to 7 April 1924.
> - Most consecutive days above 48.9 °C (120 °F): 43 days; Death Valley, California from 6 July through 17 August, 1917.
> - Surface temperature: 93.9 °C (201.0 °F), in Death Valley, California, 15 July 1972.
> - Highest temperature during rain: 46.1 °C (115.0 °F), in Needles, California, 13 August 2012.
> - Highest overnight low temperature: 44.2 °C (111.6 °F) at the Khasab weather station (WMO Index = 41241) in Oman on June 17, 2017.
> - Highest average monthly temperature: 41.9 °C (107.4 °F), in Death Valley, California, for the month of July 2017.